# Download file from shared folder using Ajax and Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to write a file download function in C# controller in order to be able to grab the file in shared folder then download it through webpage.

So right now I have got 1.filename, 2.file location, 3. file extention. So the ActionResult looks like this:

```
        public ActionResult Downloadfile(string filename, string fileloaction, string extention)
        {
        ...
        }
```

My Ajax call is:

```
 $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          cache: false,
          url: 'xxx/downloadfile',
          data: { 'filename': filename, 'fileloaction': fulllink, 'extention': extention },
          success: function () {
             ...
            },//end success
           error: function (e) {
              console.log(e.statusText);
              }//end error
            });
```

So how can I write the `Downloadfile` function in order to get the file then pass to my ajax?

Thank you!

Comment: You could return the binary stream to an Ajax call but what would you be doing with it? If you want to save it to the clients local PC you are better of to just do an anchor link to it and use the download attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jquery.fileDownload](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/), this is full example on github 
https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Views/FileDownload/Index.cshtml

**ASP.Net**

```
[HttpPost, FileDownload]
public FilePathResult DownloadReportPost(int foo)
{              
   return File("~/Report.pdf", "application/pdf", string.Format("Report{0}.pdf", id));
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("click", "a.fileDownloadPromise", function () {
     $.fileDownload($(this).prop('href'))
      .done(function () { alert('File download a success!'); })
      .fail(function () { alert('File download failed!'); });    
            return false; 
});
```